# Can't print output through loop, don't know how to print second table

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

Edit: anything would help.  If anyone can tell me the process at least I'd appreciate it.

I'm trying to get my code to read for an access database that I made.  In that database are 2 tables, one is Soccer_Team and the other is Soccer_Players.  I'm having an issue figuring out how to have the field name show up in front of the actual data.  When I run the code now I get this:

Name: Location: Home Stadium: FC Barcelona  Spain   Camp Nou
Name: Location: Home Stadium: FC Bayern Munich  Germany Allianz

I want the "Name:" to be followed by the club name, and so on...  I am not familiar with Java so I am a little confused here.

Also, I want to print the second table from my database through an SQL query, that has it display the above but with the player information printed under each row... I don't even know where to begin doing that. I'm not sure I'm explaining this well, so sorry if I'm confusing people.

Sorry if this is asking too much but I am pretty lost...  Thanks for any help guys.

```
package msjavaaccessdb;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MSjavaAccessDB {

/** Creates a new instance of databaseApplication */
public MSjavaAccessDB() {
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static String nameOfJdbcOdbcDriver =
            "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
//  static String dataBaseNameDSN = "jdbc:odbc:myDataSource";

static String dataBaseNameDSN = "jdbc:odbc:myDataSource";
static String userName = "";
static String passwordForUser = "";

static Connection myConnectionRequest = null;
static Statement myStatementObject = null;
static ResultSet myResultTuples = null;
static ResultSetMetaData myResultTuplesMetaData = null;

static String queryToBeExecuted = "select * from Soccer_Team";


public static void main(String args[])
                    throws ClassNotFoundException  {

  try {

    //Identify the driver to use
    Class.forName(nameOfJdbcOdbcDriver);

    //Attempt a connection to database...
    Connection myConnectionRequest =
            DriverManager.getConnection(
                    dataBaseNameDSN, userName, passwordForUser);

    //Create a statement object, use its method to execute query
    Statement  myStatementObject =
            myConnectionRequest.createStatement();

    //Use statement object method to execute a query.
    //Hold results in a resutl set...like a cursor
    ResultSet myResultTuples = myStatementObject.executeQuery
                                    (queryToBeExecuted);

    //Call metadata to get the number of attributes
    myResultTuplesMetaData = myResultTuples.getMetaData();
    int numberOfAttributes =
            myResultTuplesMetaData.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(numberOfAttributes));

    //For each row in result set, print ALL columns

    for(int rowNum = 1; myResultTuples.next(); rowNum++) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfAttributes; i++) {
                   if ( (i != 1) ) System.out.print (
                            myResultTuples.getString(i) + "\t");
                   else {//String xyz = myResultTuples.getString(1);    
                        int xyz = Integer.parseInt( myResultTuples.getString(1));

                        System.out.print ("Name: ");
                        System.out.print ("Location: ");
                        System.out.print ("Home Stadium: ");
                   }
            }

            System.out.println("\n\n");
    }

  }  // end of try block

  //handle ALL exceptions to above database calls
  catch (SQLException sqlError) {
    System.out.println("Unexpected exception : " +
            sqlError.toString() + ", sqlstate = " +
            sqlError.getSQLState());
    sqlError.printStackTrace();
  }

}  // end of main method of this class

}  // end of the class
```

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know how your datatable looks, but what i guess you want to do is print the column label and then the corresponding data value of the row.

```
for(int rowNum = 1; myResultTuples.next(); rowNum++) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfAttributes; i++) {
                   //print column label
                   System.out.print(myResultTuplesMetaData.getColumnLabel(i) + ": ");
                   //print data value
                   System.out.print(myResultTuples.getString(i) + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            //process SQl-Query about players and print out results in another for loop HERE
}
```

So for the second table you would have to do sth like `SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE team IS (?)` as a PreparedStatement and print out the results in another loop.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a suggestion for the second part? I am familiar with C++ but Java is foreign so I'm not sure what it's capable of.  It would need to print out the players that fit into each club...  If that helps.

Comment: I don't know what your Data looks like, but I assume that player information is another column (or multiple) in your table.
Maybe you could upload a screenshot and tell me what you exactly want to do.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now but I can upload a screen cap later.  The table is basically player name, Id, position, country of birth, and team.  There's nothing else really.  The id is the primary key and auto generated

Comment: Here's the image btw, thank you for the help earlier.  It printed perfectly, but now of course I am struggling with the second loop...  I tried to follow your edit, but it won't work.
![Image](http://imgur.com/zgvA0zJ).

Comment: Thx for the img. You have to be a specific. What won't work? What have you tried so far to solve it? Also pls add some code and output if necessary

Comment: I added an answer because I couldn't format the code in a comment.

Comment: I can't comment on other people's answers bc I have <50 reputation.
Pls post the full code and the error.

Comment: I updated my other post, if that helps. I can't update the error because I don't have access to my machine right now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the error right now because I don't have access to NetBeans at this moment.  I can update later when I am on my home computer.  I'm not sure if what I did makes sense, because I don't exactly know what the rules of Java are...  Hope this isn't stroke inducing.

```
package msjavaaccessdb;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MSjavaAccessDB {

/** Creates a new instance of databaseApplication */
public MSjavaAccessDB() {
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
*/
static String nameOfJdbcOdbcDriver =
        "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
static String dataBaseNameDSN = "jdbc:odbc:myDataSource";

static String dataBaseNameDSN = "jdbc:odbc:myDataSource";
static String userName = "";
static String passwordForUser = "";

static Connection myConnectionRequest = null;
static Statement myStatementObject = null;
static ResultSet myResultTuples = null;
static ResultSetMetaData myResultTuplesMetaData = null;
static ResultSet ResultTuples = null;
static ResultSetMetaData ResultTuplesMetaData = null;

static String queryToBeExecuted = "select * from Soccer_Team";
static string secondQuery = "select * from Soccer_Player where team is (?)";


public static void main(String args[])
                throws ClassNotFoundException  {

try {

//Identify the driver to use
Class.forName(nameOfJdbcOdbcDriver);

//Attempt a connection to database...
Connection myConnectionRequest =
        DriverManager.getConnection(
                dataBaseNameDSN, userName, passwordForUser);

//Create a statement object, use its method to execute query
Statement  myStatementObject =
        myConnectionRequest.createStatement();

//Use statement object method to execute a query.
//Hold results in a resutl set...like a cursor
ResultSet myResultTuples = myStatementObject.executeQuery
                                (queryToBeExecuted);
ResultSet ResultTuples = myStatementObject.executeQuery
                (secondQuery);

//Call metadata to get the number of attributes
myResultTuplesMetaData = myResultTuples.getMetaData();
int numberOfAttributes =
        myResultTuplesMetaData.getColumnCount();
System.out.println(Integer.toString(numberOfAttributes));


ResultTuplesMetaData = ResultTuples.getMetaData();
int numOfAttributes =
        ResultTuplesMetaData.getColumnCount();
System.out.println(Integer.toString(numOfAttributes));


//For each row in result set, print ALL columns

for(int rowNum = 1; myResultTuples.next(); rowNum++) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfAttributes; i++) {
               //print column label
               System.out.print(myResultTuplesMetaData.getColumnLabel(i) +         ": ");
               //print data value
               System.out.print(myResultTuples.getString(i) + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");
}

for(int rowNum = 1; ResultTuples.next(); rowNum++) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numOfAttributes; i++) {
               //print column label
               System.out.print(ResultTuplesMetaData.getColumnLabel(i) + ": ");
               //print data value
               System.out.print(ResultTuples.getString(i) + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");
  }
}  // end of try block

//handle ALL exceptions to above database calls
catch (SQLException sqlError) {
  System.out.println("Unexpected exception : " +
        sqlError.toString() + ", sqlstate = " +
        sqlError.getSQLState());
    sqlError.printStackTrace();
  }

}  // end of main method of this class

}  // end of the class
```